# Publish automatically an article in Joomla 1.7

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

i have a site where users can write articles on their own from frontend.
at the moment, i need to manually publish every article they create, is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Which role are you giving to your users?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your permissions. It's a pain to manage Joomla permissions on a standard install, get ACL Manager and it's very easy to set up the correct permissions. It's 10.00€ but worth every penny.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. It is also relatively hard to get the settings correct because the permissions are located in several different places. ACL Manager simply takes all of the built in Joomla ACL settings and puts them in one place so you can easily see what is set up wrong. It is not a replacement for Joomla ACL, it is an add on tool to make it easier.